Cannot unpack my own packer with x64dbg - scylla
I wrote a simple virtualization-obfuscated x64 packer. But my problem is I cannot dump and unpack it with Scylla. For who wants to analyze this exe themself, set BP at 00007FF630DB26A1. The call at this address will get you to OEP. When I dump it and fix the imports, the program breaks and EntryPoint looks incorrect. I allocated the memory space by VirtualAlloc. Maybe Scylla cant dump dynamic memory spaces but idk.
Packed EXE : https://dosya.co/eciwyncesp7k/packed.exe.html
Also I recommend analyzing this file with ScyllaHide full options.
